# Checking for temporal autocorrelation in experience sampling data - how to interpret the variogram?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, variogram

I have day-level data from about 100 participants from 11 days (EDIT. a subset of participants responded for 12 days, which is why there's a distance of 11 in the variogram table). I'm interested in predicting a rating they made each evening about how satisfied they were with their day from self-reported behavior during the day. I'm also interested in possible individual differences in this relationship.

I'd like to ignore the effect of time (day) as I'm not interested in it and I'm convinced the days as such are interchangeable re: the variables I'm investigating. So, I was thinking of a model like this

```
model1<-lmer(satisfaction ~ behavior + (behavior|id), data=data) #behavior will be participant-mean centered at the day level and id=participant id
```

Then I was going to plot the random slopes and just visually present the possible individual differences in the slopes or the lack of them.

However, I have recently learned that one should check for possible temporal autocorrelation when modeling this type of longitudinal data. After reading Frank Harrell's regression modeling strategies [this chapter](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long), I ran a model like this:

```
model2<-lme(satisfaction ~ 1, data=data, ~day|id)
```

And then I extracted a variogram, which I understand is one way of checking for such autocorrelation:

```
var<-Variogram(model2, form = ~day|id)
var
     variog dist n.pairs
1  0.8237239    1     791
2  0.9749700    2     713
3  1.1072367    3     625
4  1.1876627    4     548
5  1.0150065    5     476
6  0.9009881    6     401
7  0.9012620    7     335
8  0.8441357    8     261
9  1.0409384    9     180
10 0.9917527   10     110
11 0.9433487   11      36

plot(var)
```

[image]

However, I don't know how to interpret the table or the image as the variogram is practically never used in my field and I have no examples (the variogram use tutorials I have found are mostly from agriculture or geography and I can't wrap my head around to how to apply them to my data). Based on some scraps of information I've found, I'd say the temporal autocorrelation is weak overall, and does not vary much by time lag, and so maybe I can ignore it. Would that be correct?

Another question is whether I should extract the variogram from my actual model, i.e. write `model1` in nlme language, add the day|id random effect and then extract the variogram from this model? Or can I use the truncated model2?

Thank you in advance if anyone can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot indicates the semivariance initially increases with the day interval, which is typical as observations further apart in time are generally less correlated. However, it doesn't show a clear trend of increasing continuously with distance. It increases up to a certain point (around day 4), then seems to decrease slightly, and further oscillates without a clear increasing or decreasing pattern.

This pattern suggests that there isn't a strong temporal autocorrelation in the satisfaction ratings with respect to the day interval. This would support your initial assumption that the effect of time (day) can be ignored as the days are interchangeable regarding the variables you're investigating. `nlme` can fit models with a number of different residual variance structures, so you might want to try some of these and compare the model fits with AIC.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped! I will try the different residual variance structures.

Comment: Happy to help. Another thought: since your main (only?) interest is in prediction rather than inference (e.g. causal effects). While ‘nlme‘ is very flexible in its range of residual covariance structures I find it a little complicated. A much newer package is ‘mmrm’ (mixed models repeated measures) that is developed by statisticians in bigpharma with the explicit aim to replicate the results obtained by SAS.

Comment: Thank you for the package recommendation! I'll check it out as nlme is indeed very complex. And sorry for the confusion, actually my goal is inference, I used "prediction" just to clarify what are IV and DV in the model.